# how to gat data form table1 which does't contains that id and user name in table2

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a tables like Table 1 and Table2

Table1 contains

```
id  |  area  | Merchant
-----------------------------
1   | Area1  | Merchant1
-----------------------------
2   | Area1  | Merchant2
-----------------------------
3   | Area2  | Merchant3
-----------------------------
4   | Area3  | Merchant4
-----------------------------
```

Table2 contains

```
id  |merchant_id| user_id
-----------------------------
1   | 1         | user1
-----------------------------
2   | 2         | user2
-----------------------------
3   | 1         | user2
-----------------------------
4   | 1         | user3
-----------------------------
```

My question was, I want to show the merchant names from the Table1 but it should not contains in Table2 for the users when they longed in.

This Query not working please help me

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.merchant
FROM table1 AS t1 ,table2 AS t2
WHERE (t1.id NOT LIKE t2.merchant_id AND t2.user_id NOT LIKE 'user1') AND
      t1.area like 'area1'
```

Comment: Can you share the result you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT      CA.ID

           ,CA.MERCHANT

FROM       CITY_AREA_PLACE AS CA

WHERE CA.ID NOT IN ( SELECT FL.MERCHANT_ID

                     FROM USER_FAV_LIST AS FL

                     WHERE  FL.USER_ID = 'STARINGH@GMAIL.COM'

                           AND CA.AREA = 'GACHIBOWLI' );
```